# OkHTTP checking response is null pattern?

Tags: java, okhttp

I am using the OkHttp client and when I wrote the code to consume an API, I am getting a SonarLint warning about `response.body().string()` could be null.

However there is a chicken and egg problem with response in that it can only be consumed once, then it is de-referenced.

Which means I have had to structure my code like so:

Check the response object is not null

Then check the response body text is not null/empty

Which results in two separate but similar if statement/catches

```
try (var response = okHttpClient.newCall(siteMagicLinkRequest).execute()) {
        if (response.body() == null) {
            throw new ApiException("Unable to generate Magic Link: Null Response Body from site");
        }
        var responseString = response.body().string();
        if (response.body() == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(responseString)) {
            throw new ApiException("Unable to generate Magic Link: Empty Response Body From site");
        }

        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            return responseString;
        } else {
            final siteApiErrorResponse errorResponse = gson.fromJson(responseString, siteApiErrorResponse.class);
            throw new ApiException(response.code(), errorResponse.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AuthorizationException("Unable to generate Magic Link: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I can't use a condensed if check as shown below, as it will lose the response body.

```
 if (response.body() == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(responseString)) {
            throw new ApiException("Unable to generate Magic Link: Empty Response Body From site");
        }
```

Is there any OkHttp API or another pattern I can use to simplify this code and remove the extra if statement/trap?

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```java
if (response.body() == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(response.body().string())) {
     throw new ApiException("Unable to generate Magic Link: Empty Response Body From site");
}
```

If the `response.body() == null` check before the or-operator is `true`, the check after the or-operator will not be executed. Instead, it will execute the code inside the if-statement right away. The second check will only be executed if the first check returns `false`.

That's why you will never get a `NullPointerException` with this if-statement. And this is what I think you are concerned about, right?